# Manually set access token in js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently working on an iOS application that uses Facebook for login and wants to use facebook comments.

Facebook comments is not supported in the iOS SDK nor is it accessible using the /graph API. So we are forced to use the web version of this.

Now we want the users to be required to login inside the app using the iOS SDK first before allowing them to use comments. But since both use different cookies, while you can be logged in in the app, that doesn't mean that the loaded webview will properly represent the logged in user (if he is logged in at all).

Now I dug trough  the facebook js sdk a little bit and found a few mentions of setAccessToken, which offcourse are private methods I cannot access, so is there any way for me to force, or fake however you will call it the javascript SDK login? With the information I have recieved from the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, answering my own question so other can see.

Basically with just the iOS SDK this is not possible. To persist this session for javascript you would need what is called the signed_request. The data required to create this signed request is not available in the iOS sdk.

A possible workaround would be to have a seperate back-end. Send the oauth information there ( for example a PHP setup). Use the PHP SDK To authorise said oauth information. The PHP sdk does allow you to retrieve the signed request. Return this request to the client (app) and use this to set the authResponse data of facebook. (I have not used this setup, but it would be a way to get the signed request)